# Angular 2 - Change in One Component Not Triggering onChanges in Another

Tags: angular

I am trying to get changes from one grid to flow into another, and subsequently update one of the rows in that underlying datasource. In the attached plunker, I basically want the underlying datasource of `Bar` to have the `TotalSalary` row updated with the total salary that is calculated from `Foo`. The total salary gets passed down upon hitting enter in the textbox.

I have gotten it working by emitting `Foo.getSalaryTotal()` instead of `Foo` itself; however, I would prefer to pass through `Foo` because I can foresee myself wanting multiple fields passed through and not wanting to have tons of inputs/ouputs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4sw4yhzDTep4j0jGLDhD?p=preview

Comment: you could try creating a centralized service that handles the data or you can have the directives(if the components are directives) pass eachother their own controllers and $watch their variables.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered almost the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34298708/215945).

Since `foosGrid` is being (re)set to the same `foos` object in `foosChanged()`, Angular will not notice the change because `foosGrid` is still referencing the same object.

One option is to implement `ngDoCheck()` in your `Bar` component and perform a custom check to see if the properties of the `foos` object in `Bar` have changed.