# In angular2, how to get onChanges for properties changed on an object sent in for an @Input

Tags: angular

I have a directive and on it is an `@Input` that accepts a class.

```ts
@Directive({selector: 'my-directive'})
@View({directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]})
export class MyDirective  {
    @Input() inputSettings : SettingsClass;
    @Input() count : number;

   onChanges(map) {
      console.log('onChanges');
    }
}
```

The directive is used in html:

```ts
  ...
  <my-directive [input-settings]="settings" [count]="settings.count"></my-directive>
  ...
```

If the settings.count is changed then the `onChanges` will fire. If any other property on the settings class changes, then it will not fire.

How can I detect if there is a change to any property on settings?

Comment: My guess is this (currently?) doesn't work... maybe because `inputSettings` contains a reference to an instance of an object and since the reference itself doesn't change, Angular probably doesn't try to compare object properties so it does not see or report a change.  (I hope I'm wrong, or I hope they fix this.)

Comment: Indeed, [Victor Savkin's blog post](http://victorsavkin.com/post/133936129316/angular-immutability-and-encapsulation) confirmed my assumptions: "If the address object is mutable, some other component can update the street property without creating a new address object. If this happens, the onChanges hook won’t be called".

Comment: you can also use getter and setter for the attribute input property

Comment: can you please explain your code sample? why would `onChanges()` ever be called?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Angular will only notice if the object has been changed to a different object (i.e., the object reference changed), so `ngOnChanges()` can't be used to solve your problem.  See [Victor Savkin's blog post](https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487) for more information.

You could implement the [`ngDoCheck()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck) method in your MyDirective class.  That lifecycle hook is called "every time that the input properties of a component or a directive are checked. Use it to extend change detection by performing a custom check."

To implement your custom check method, you would first need to implement an `.equals()` method on class `SettingsClass` such that you could then write code something like the following in `ngDoCheck()`:

```
ngDoCheck() {
   if(!this.inputSettings.equals(this.previousInputSettings)) {
      // inputSettings changed
      // some logic here to react to the change
      this.previousInputSettings = this.inputSettings;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An other solution , which is useful when you don't have control on the object you are passing to the component, is to use ViewChild and directly call a method to update the object :

In the child component add a function like :

```
public updateSettings(obj: SettingsClass) {
    this.inputSettings  = obj;
}
```

And in the parent component call the updateSettings function :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mycomponnent',
    templateUrl: './my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class PlayComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(MyDirectiveComponent,{static: false}) mydirective;

    elsewhereinthecode() {
        // When you need to update call : 
        mydirective.updateSettings(settingsObject);
    }
}
```