# How does Angular 2 change detection work?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 1, change detection was by dirty checking the $scope hierarchy. We would implicitly or explicitly create watchers in our templates, controllers or components.

In Angular 2 we no longer have $scope, but we do override setInterval, setTimeout, et al. I can see how Angular might use this to trigger a $digest, but how does Angular determine what has changed, especially given that Object.observe never made it into browsers?

### Example

Here is a simple example. An object defined in a service is updated in a setInterval. The DOM is recompiled each interval.

How is Angular able to tell that the AppComponent is watching the service, and that the value of an attribute of the service has changed?

```
var InjectedService = function() {
  var val = {a:1}
  setInterval(() => val.a++, 1000);
  return val;
}

var AppComponent = ng.core
  .Component({
    selector: "app",
    template:
    `
      {{service.a}}
    `
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function(service) {
      this.service = service;
    }
  })

AppComponent.parameters = [ new ng.core.Inject( InjectedService ) ];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent, [InjectedService])
});
```

Comment: @PascalPrecht heard your prayers! http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: @EricMartinez - That is indeed a very good article :)

Comment: Good presentation on change deduction strategy URL - http://pascalprecht.github.io/slides/angular-2-change-detection-explained. Say thanks to @PascalPrecht :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Angular creates a change detector object (see [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)) per component, which tracks the last value of each template binding, such as `{{service.a}}`.  By default, after every asynchronous browser event (such as a response from a server, or a click event, or a timeout event), Angular change detection executes and  dirty checks every binding using those change detector objects.

If a change is detected, the change is propagated. E.g.,

- If an input property value changed, the new value is propagated to the component's input property.
- If a `{{}}` binding value changed, the new value is propagated to DOM property `textContent`.
- If the value of `x` changes in a style, attribute, or class binding – i.e., `[style.x]` or `[attr.x]` or `[class.x]` – the new value is propagated to the DOM to update the style, HTML attribute, or class.

Angular uses Zone.js to create its own zone ([NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html)), which monkey-patches all asynchronous events (browser DOM events, timeouts, AJAX/XHR).  This is how change detection is able to automatically run after each asynchronous event.  I.e., after each asynchronous event handler (function) finishes, Angular change detection will execute.

I have a lot more detail and reference links in this answer:  [What is the Angular2 equivalent to an AngularJS $watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569094/what-is-the-angular2-equivalent-to-an-angularjs-watch/34570122#34570122)

Comment: So would I be right to say that it is still checking everything every time anything changes?

Comment: @superluminary, yes, by default, it dirty checks all template bindings every time change detection runs.  (If a component is marked `OnPush`, it may skip over that component if no input properties have changed.)

Answer (score 18):

### Zone.js

Changes happen as a *reaction* to something, so in this respect they are asynchronous. They are caused by asynchronous *actions*, and in the browser world those are [**Events**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events). To intercept those events angular uses [zone.js](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/), which patches JavaScript call stack (I beleive, someone correct me if I'm wrong) and exposes hooks that can be used to take other actions.

```
function angular() {...}
zone.run(angular);
```

If you imagine this `angular` function is the entire Angular, this would be how it is run in zone. By doing so **Events** can be intercepted and if they are triggered we can assume changes happen, and listen/watch for them.

### ApplicationRef

In reality [`ApplicationRef`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.ts#L72-L77) creates the zone:

```
/**
 * Create an Angular zone.
 */
export function createNgZone(): NgZone {
  return new NgZone({enableLongStackTrace: assertionsEnabled()});
}
```

and class `NgZone` is created with [few event emitters](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/modules/angular2/src/core/zone/ng_zone.ts#L159-L172):

```
  this._onTurnStartEvents = new EventEmitter(false);
  this._onTurnDoneEvents = new EventEmitter(false);
  this._onEventDoneEvents = new EventEmitter(false);
  this._onErrorEvents = new EventEmitter(false);
```

that it exposes to the outside world via getters:

```
  get onTurnStart(): /* Subject */ any { return this._onTurnStartEvents; }
  get onTurnDone() { return this._onTurnDoneEvents; }
  get onEventDone() { return this._onEventDoneEvents; }
  get onError() { return this._onErrorEvents; }
```

When `ApplicationRef` is [created](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.ts#L394-L401) it subscribes to the zone's events, specifically `onTurnDone()`:

```
this.zone.onTurnDone
  .subscribe(() => this.zone.run(() => this.tick());
```

### Changes

When events are triggered [`tick()`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/application_ref.ts#L486-L502) function is run which loops through every component:

```
  this._changeDetectorRefs.forEach((detector) => detector.detectChanges());
```

and [detects changes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/abstract_change_detector.ts#L104-L123) based on components' `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Those changes are collected as an array of [`SimpleChange`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.7/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detection_util.ts#L100-L106) objects:

```
addChange(changes: {[key: string]: any}, oldValue: any, newValue: any): {[key: string]: any} {
  if (isBlank(changes)) {
    changes = {};
  }
  changes[this._currentBinding().name] = ChangeDetectionUtil.simpleChange(oldValue, newValue);
  return changes;
}
```

witch is available for us through [`onChanges`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) interface:

```
export interface OnChanges { 
  ngOnChanges(changes: {[key: string]: SimpleChange}); 
}
```

Comment: "loops though every component" -- although you mentioned the ChangeDetectionStrategy, I think it is worth noting that if a component is marked `OnPush`, it is normally skipped, unless it is specifically [marked/flagged for change detection](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#markForCheck).  If it is marked, it is checked, and then it unmarked.

Comment: "those changes are collected" -- I think it is worth noting that only input property changes are collected and delivered to us via `ngOnChanges()`.  Other changes (e.g., template bindings like `{{}}`) are not included.  And because changes are detected by comparing values, if the input property is a JavaScript reference type (e.g., an array, object, etc.), we are only notified if the reference (value) changes.  If the array ref doesn't change, but, say, an item of the array does change,  `ngOnChanges()` doesn't notify us.  (I mention this because this scenario has come up a few times on SO.)