# how to clear input field after pushing item on array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I made a simple example of angular 2. I added item in an array. When user types anything and press the button, it is added into the array and get displayed in the list .

I am facing two issues

- 1 ) how to clear input field after pusing to array ?
- 2 ) How angular 2 works ? As in document Angular 2 remove watches .So
  when item is added in array .how template show updated list .how ?

  is it watching the model of list ?

Here is my [plunker code](http://plnkr.co/edit/oCxrgxNlCkjVnTrhZGQA?p=preview)

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Ionic 2
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="has-header">
 <ion-list style="border:2px solid grey;height:500px">
  <ion-item *ngFor="#item of Todo">
{{item.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label" >Add Todo</span>
  <input type="text" #todo placeholder="Add todo" >
</label>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer-bar (click)="addItem(todo.value)">

  <h1 class="title" style='color:red'>Add Todo!</h1>

</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: [Check this post](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) about your second question. It's too long of an explanation to put in an answer :)

Comment: I will read .could you please example in few words

Comment: Read the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469024/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-work), they explain it much better than I ever could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear the input fields by doing the following things.

**Home.html**

previous code

```
<ion-footer-bar (click)="addItem(todo.value)">

  <h1 class="title" style='color:red'>Add Todo!</h1>

</ion-footer-bar>
```

changed code

```
<ion-footer-bar (click)="addItem(todo)">

  <h1 class="title" style='color:red'>Add Todo!</h1>

</ion-footer-bar>
```

Modify the addItem function in **home.ts** like below.

```
addItem(v){
      this.Todo.push({name:v.value})
      v.value='';
    }
```

Hope this gives you a solution for the problem you faced. There are so many other ways too. Since you get the value from the id, I have given the solution based on that.

> updated plunker code below

http://plnkr.co/edit/oCxrgxNlCkjVnTrhZGQA?p=preview

Answer for the deleting issue.

instead of this

```
deleteTodo(obj){
      alert('----');
      var index =  this.Todo.indexOf(obj);
  this.Todo.splice(index, 1); 
    }
```

follow this

```
    deleteTodo(name){
      var index =  this.Todo.indexOf(name);
  this.Todo.splice(index, 1); 
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 6):

Instead of clearing the value in the function you can do on the click event too like this :-

```
<ion-footer-bar (click)="addItem(todo.value);todo.value = ''">

  <h1 class="title" style='color:red'>Add Todo!</h1>

</ion-footer-bar>
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ydpiTU3yH6tKcF7yOJd4?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: you are trying to get Index of `item` which is not exist try using `obj` as parameter here is working code http://plnkr.co/edit/w28WaXb3VA4fK0IaCxpo?p=preview