# How does angular detect model changes in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am new in angular 2 and going through some tutorial for learning.Most of the things I got to understand but one thing which I am still not getting is how angular 2 detect the model changes or how digest cycle run in angular 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Angular 2 change detection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469024/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-work)

Comment: read these two articles [Angular’s $digest is reborn in the newer version of Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e) and [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)