# How does Angular detect changes and update the component view?

Tags: angular

Using a new angular project:

Consider the following **app.component.ts** (notice the `redSelected` boolean)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  redSelected = false;

}
```

It has the following **app.component.html**

```
<h2>Choose:</h2>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="red" (change)="redSelected = true">
  <span>Red</span>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" (change)="redSelected = false">
  <span>Blue</span>
</label>
<p *ngIf="redSelected">Whoooorraay! Red is here.</p>
```

Whenever *the Red radiobox* is selected, the final paragraph appears. When *the Blue radiobox* is selected the paragraph disappears.

How is it possible that angular detects this change and updates the component html view?

**Note:** I tried replacing the final paragraph with

```
<p [ngClass]="hideOrShow()">Whoooorraay! Red is here.</p>
```

where `hideOrShow()` is defined (inside app.component.ts) as the following:

```
hideOrShow() {
  if (this.redSelected === false) return 'hidden';
}
```

and `hidden` is a css class (inside app.component.css)

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

The same behavior continues... Angular is able to detect the change in the value of `redSelected` and updates the component view html automatically.

**My question is:** what triggers this re-evaluation? what is being re-evaluated exactly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/35469024/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks a lot! I have been trying to find documentation on this but without knowing the correct terminology. If there is any official docs on the topic, kindly link it here. Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

Each angular component has attached change detector that test changes in templates variables. You can read more about it [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/)