# Global events (window.onresize) didn't change the local variable's value

Tags: typescript, angular, atscript

Global events (window.onresize) didn't change the local variable's value.

```js
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    a: number = 0;
    b: number = 0;
    ngOnInit() {
        window.onresize = () => {
            this.a = 10;
            this.b = 10;
        };
    }
}
```

[image: enter image descssription here]

Answer (score 1):

Bind to global events using host binding (this is mentioned in the API docs, [deep inside the DirectiveMetadata page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DirectiveMetadata-class.html#!#host-anchor)):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<p>Resize window and look at console log.
    <p>{{a}} {{b}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostListener('window:resize') onResize() {
    this.a++;
    this.b++;
    console.log(this.a, this.b, event)
  }
}
```

<kbd>[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tzUbjpj3dcKucilNAUcg?p=preview)</kbd>

Your original code does not work because you monkey-patched the `onresize` handler (that Angular had originally monkey-patched) to your own function.  So, Angular no longer has a way to run change detection after the event handler finishes.  Using host binding keeps the Angular monkey-patch in place, hence it does not disable change detection, hence your view will update after the resize event fires.

Answer (score 0):

> didn't change the local variable's value

From your screenshot I can see that `this.b = 10` so it did change the variable value.

[image]

In the picture you also see `a: number = 0`. That is just the value of `a` since the last breakpoint. You can see `this.a` is also `10`

Comment: Hi...That is a line of code where i put breakpoint. that is not a actual value. Without changing the local variable, how do i change the ui value. Please guide me to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem by forcing the update code to run in the Angular Zone.  The documentation I followed is at https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/DirectiveMetadata-class.html (current as of today 10/8/16).

Something like this should work:

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgZone} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    window.onresize = () => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
            this.a = 10;
            this.b = 10;
        }
    };
}
```

This is simpler than [Mark Rajcok's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135449/1019307) answer in this question, however NG2 is still a moving target so no doubt what I have written is one of the improvements that have been made (eg. the link to DirectiveMetadata no longer exists).