# Match all phrases and push element to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I am trying to match all typed phrases(characters) with main array. I have a big array, when user types something i want to search my array and show only matching entries, for example: if user types puzzle then from my array 'my puzzle starts','enter your puzzle' these both should match.

I have created **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wnsfyf2/)** here, here is my html code

```
Search: <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="search" /><br />
Results: <input type="text" id="results_count" /><br />
<textarea id="results_text" style="width:300px; height:500px"></textarea>
```

My js code

```
var string =['1234sud','man in puzzle','rocking roll','1232 -powernap','all_broswers'];
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var search = $(this).val();
  var resultsText = $('#results_text');
  var resultsCount = $('#results_count');
  if (!search) {
    resultsText.val('');
    resultsCount.val('0');
    return;
  }
  var j = 0, results = [],result;
  for   (var i=0;i<string.length;i++){
  var rx = new RegExp('"([*'+search+'*])"','gi');

  if (rx.exec(string[i])) {
    results.push(string[i]);
    j += 1;
    if (j >=100)
      break;
  }
  }

  //results=string;
  resultsText.val(results);
  console.log(results)
  resultsCount.val(j);
});
```

I am not able to write that regular expression which matches types phrases (characters) with array and pushes matching element to result array. Any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no need in `RegExp`. You can use `indexOf` function to collect matching strings in the array.

Comment: can you please edit my fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize the case and use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {


  var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase(),
  // add validation that search isn't empty, return if it is

   // create results array
   results =  string.filter(function(s){
      return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(search)>-1;
   })
   // do something with results


})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but its saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null, this is because i am using angularjs array? please reply

Comment: Also can you please look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48355599/loading-large-array-in-oi-select-takes-too-much-of-time-in-angularjs/48357859#48357859 question too? all i am doing to work this only.

Comment: do you have holes in that array? Or `null` values? And why are you using jQuery for any of this in angular app?

Comment: I want to use regular expression to filter large array, yeah that array may have nulls, if you check my question with bounty there i am loading data on scroll down, but search is not working so i asked this question.

Comment: Ok so change it to `return s && s.toLowerCase().indexOf(search)>-1;`. And/or filter nulls from array

Comment: Yes thank you that worked, can you please check my bounty question?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = ['1234sud', 'man in puzzle', 'rocking roll', '1232 -powernap', 'all_broswers'];
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var search = $(this).val();
  var resultsText = $('#results_text');
  var resultsCount = $('#results_count');
  if (!search) {
    resultsText.val('');
    resultsCount.val('0');
    return;
  }
  var j = 0,
    results = [],
    result;
    
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i].indexOf(search) > -1) {
      results.push(string[i]);
      j += 1;
      if (j >= 100)
        break;
    }
  }

  //results=string;
  resultsText.val(results);
  console.log(results)
  resultsCount.val(j);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search: <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="search" /><br /> Results: <input type="text" id="results_count" /><br />
<textarea id="results_text" style="width:300px; height:500px"></textarea>
```

Use [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function, it's exactly what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but its saying TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null when i am trying in y project files, i have very big array to filter.

Comment: Did you run the snippet?

Comment: Yeah there its fine, but mine is angularjs array so for that is it causing any problem?

Comment: It shouldn't. Try to make a debug and print the value of your Array `console.log(string)[i]`

Comment: Thank you for your response and answer one upvote from me.

Answer (score 0):

Your simplest solution: don't use regex.

For this particular problem, you're best off just looking for the index of the substring, using `indexOf`.

```js
const words = ['hello', 'jello', 'cake', 'pie'];
const term = 'ello';

const result = words.filter(word => word.indexOf(term) > -1);
console.log(result);
```

You don't specify, but if you want word only matches (as oppose to partial word matches like I have above), you could pad it with a space.

If you insist on using regex, then all you need is the word itself:

```js
const words = ['hello', 'jello', 'cake', 'pie'];
const term = 'ello';

const result = words.filter(word => (new RegExp(term, 'gi')).test(word));
console.log(result);
```

You don't need any fancy symbols or groupings or anything.

A regex of `/ello/` just means "find this word anywhere in the string". Since there isn't a `^` or `$`, it isn't limited by start or end, so no need for wildcards.

Also, use `test()` instead of `exec()`, since `test()` resolves to a boolean, it's more accurate for an `if` statement.

Again, if you want whole words, you could just wrap it in spaces with the start and end having `/[^\s]word[\s$]/` which would means "either a space or the start of the phrase" and "either a space or the end of the phrase".

Answer (score 0):

Use String.match if you need exact match:

```
if (search.match(string[i])) {
  results.push(string[i]);
  j += 1;
}
```

Or dynamically created regex for case of not exact match:

```
var rxs = '.*' + search + '.*';
var rx = new RegExp(rxs,'gi');
```

Comment: OP not looking for exact match. See ..  *"if user types puzzle..."*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use a filter() for that task.

```
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
const result = words.filter(word => word.length > 6);
// const result = words.filter(word => word.indexOf(words.search) >= 0);
console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
const words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
let checkWord = "elite"

words.forEach(x=>{
    checkWord.match(new RegExp(x)
})
```