# Angular2. How to observer sub-object changes?

Tags: typescript, angular, observable

Suppose I have component with

```
@Input() timeData: TimeData
```

where `TimeData` contains only one field: `time`.

I want to observe `timeData.time`, **assuming that only `timeData.time` was changed (not the whole `timeData`)**

`ngOnChanges` doesn't track such change, while `{{timeData.time}}` works perfect.

My final goal is to set flag `goodTime`

```
if(timeData.time % 10 === 0){
    goodTime = true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't provide information about how your `TimeData` looks like but when you add an `EventEmitter` you can subcribe to changes.

```
class TimeData {
  _time: number;
  get time(): number {
    return this._time;
  }
  set time(value: number) {
    this._time = number;
    timeChange.next(number);
  }
  timeChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
}
```

use it like

```
timeData.timeChange.subscribe((value) => { doSomething(value);}
```

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much :-)
However I wonder how Angular2 does it. {{timeData.time}} works, without additional fields (timeChange, _time).

Comment: All bindings are checked in each change detection cycle. You could do this as well by implementing `doCheck()` in your component and compare the previous value with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

I did't noticed that before, but someone else also posed similar question:

[How to get onChanges for properties changed on an object sent in for an @Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124735/in-angular2-how-to-get-onchanges-for-properties-changed-on-an-object-sent-in-fo)