# Looking for analog of RxJs ofObjectChanges method in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to create class property decorator which will look for all changes of this property and do some stuff. How can i do that?

In RxJs i found `ofObjectChanges` method
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/ofobjectchanges.md

but looks like that method does not exist in angular2 RxJs version.

That method must trigger on changes of object, for example with Array.push();

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124735/in-angular2-how-to-get-onchanges-for-properties-changed-on-an-object-sent-in-fo

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there's no (yet?) implementation of that method in RxJs 5 beta currently used in Angular 2: [Migrating from RxJs 4 to 5](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md). But it is not actually clear if you really need it.

If you use typescript then you can see about writing decorators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator). Also, you can look into angular's sources, kind of starting point is modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/directives.ts. You can see how angular team implemented @Input() decorator and figure out how to do it in your case which sounds pretty similar to me.